# Only move folders not existing in target directory

Tags: linux, filesystems, rsync, mv

I am looking for a way to move folders that are not already present in the target directory on my linux server.

Example:

**Target directory**

```
folder1
folder2
folder3
folder4
```

**Source directory**

```
folder1
folder2
folder5
folder6
folder7
```

I do not want `folder1` and `folder2` from the source directory to overwrite the folders in the target directory. The contents within `folder1` and `folder2` in the source directory may be different than in the target directory but I don't want these changes copied.

This is on a CentOS 7 server and any tool needed for the job is accepted.

The list of folders not to move is dynamic so I don't want to set it up statically.

Comment: I think you may have to do this programmatically (bash or python script, or whatever).

Comment: @Halfgaar - That's also fine as it's also written in the question `any tool needed for the job is accepted.`

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by setting up a loop through each directory in the source and if there's no directory in the target by that name, it moves it:
bourne snippit:

```
for dir in `cd "$sourcedir" ; ls -1F | grep '/'`
do
  if [ ! -d "${targetdir}/${dir}" ]
  then
    mv "$dir" "${targetdir}/"
  fi
done
```

Note that this will either break or overwrite a file if you have a file in the target with the same name as a directory in the source.  If you want it robust, you should add some additional checks.

Comment: This will fail on directories with spaces. I would use `find -print0` and `xargs`.